# Very slow Sequelize findAndCountAll query with nested "include"

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm very new to using sequelize. I have a query with nested `include`s as follows:

```
Site.findAndCountAll({
        where,
        order: orderCondition,
        ...(orderAfter ? {} : limits),
        include: [
            {
                model: Version,
                as: 'versions',
                limit: 1,
                separate: true,
                order: [['version_id', 'DESC']],
                attributes: ['status', 'config'],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: User,
                        as: 'updatedByUser',
                        attributes: ['email'],
                        paranoid: false,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                model: Version,
                as: 'prod_version',
                separate: false,
                required: false,
                attributes: ['status', 'config'],
                where: {
                    is_prod: 1,
                    status: 'SUCCESS',
                },
                include: [
                    {
                        model: User,
                        as: 'updatedByUser',
                        attributes: ['email'],
                        paranoid: false,
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
        distinct: true,
    });
```

And I have these associations between Site and Version:

```
Site.hasMany(models.Version, {
    foreignKey: 'site_id',
    as: 'versions',
});
Site.hasOne(models.Version, {
    foreignKey: 'site_id',
    as: 'prod_version',
});
```

This query can take several seconds to load a page when navigating through the pagination. It takes longer the further along I go through the pages. It's fine for the first ~10-15 pages but then starts getting increasingly slower and by page 30-40 it sometimes takes more than 5 seconds to get a response.

I know there's an inherent issue with the way `OFFSET` works in SQL but I feel it shouldn't be this slow unless I'm hundreds of pages in. How else could I potentially optimize this query? A big part of the slowdown also seems to be the second item in `include`, `prod_version`. With that commented out I get a huge improvement of the response time. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Could you show the generated SQL for the main query in the post (formatted)?

Comment: Also, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.